# How can I prove $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n|=|A_1|+|A_2|+...+|A_n|$ using induction?

Tags: combinatorics, induction, cardinals

> For pairwise disjoint sets $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ how can I prove that: $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n|=|A_1|+|A_2|+...+|A_n|$ using induction and the 2-set addition rule?

**2-set addition rule:** $|A_i \cup A_j|=|A_i| + |A_j|$ if $A_i$ and $A_j$ are disjoint.

I think I should suppose the proposition holds for $P(k)$ for $k\ge 2$, that is:
$$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_k|=|A_1|+|A_2|+...+|A_k|$$

Our base case is $P(2)$:
$$P(2)=|A_1 \cup A_2|=|A_1|+|A_2|$$
By the 2-set addition principle ($A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint).

Now

$$P(k+1) = |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_k \cup A_{k+1}|$$

And $A_{k+1}$ is disjoint with $(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_k)$ since $A_{k+1} \cap (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_k) = (A_{k+1} \cap A_1) \cup (A_{k+1} \cap A_2) \cup...\cup (A_{k+1} \cap A_k) = \emptyset$

So by the 2-set addition rule:

$$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_k| + |A_{k+1}|=|A_1|+|A_2|+...+|A_k|+|A_{k+1}|$$
Which is what the proposition would conclude for $P(k+1)$ so the original proposition must be true.

**My question:** is there anything wrong with this proof attempt?

Comment: I found no error. It is absolutely fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Base case**: For $n = 2$, $|A_1∪A_2| = |A_1| + |A_2|$.

**Inductive hypothesis**: Assume that the statement holds true for some integer $k$, that is $$|A_1∪A_2∪\cdots∪A_k| = |A_1| + |A_2| + \cdots + |A_k|$$

**Inductive step**: To prove that the statement holds true for $k+1$, we need to prove that $$|A_1∪A_2∪\cdots∪A_{k+1}| = |A_1| + |A_2| + \cdots + |A_k| + |A_{k+1}|$$

By the definition of union, we have
$$|A_1∪A_2∪\cdots∪A_{k+1}| = |(A_1∪A_2∪\cdots∪A_k) ∪ A_{k+1}|$$

By the inductive hypothesis we know that $$|A_1∪A_2∪\cdots∪A_k| = |A_1| + |A_2| + \cdots + |A_k|$$

So by the definition of union,
$$|(A_1∪A_2∪\cdots ∪A_k) ∪ A_{k+1}| = |A_1| + |A_2| + \cdots + |A_k| + |A_{k+1}|$$

**Conclusion**: Since the statement holds true for $n = 2$ and for any $k$, it holds true for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: Very well formatted